# Custom Quick Action on click on widget

Tags: android, android-widget, quickaction

I have a problem. The constructor of

```
QuickAction qa = new QuickAction(v);
```

require View v, but how I can recieve parent view in AppWidgetProvider?
this I use for register click

```
PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);

     remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton1, actionPendingIntent);
```

next I try to recieve view to create 'from' my QuickAction

```
mView = mView.findViewById(R.layout.main);
      qa = new QuickAction(mView);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I know: view of QuickAction doesn't work with RemoteView. Perhaps you need to twist the code of QuickAction xml to able to do that. However I definitely recommend you shouldn't waste time on this if you do not have enough knowledge of customize view in Android :)